# Validation of date input fields in React

Tags: validation, date, reactjs, redux-form

i have to date input fields which i defined like this:

```
const MyDatePicker = ({ input, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
  <div>
    <DatePicker
      {...input} dateFormat="DD-MM-YYYY"
      selected={input.value ? moment(input.value, 'DD-MM-YYYY') : null}
    />
    {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
  </div>
);
```

I use redux form for this. I want to add a validation with the following functionality. When the date in the "Date To Field" is lesser than the date in the "Date From" field a message will be shown that the date to field must me greater that the date from field. As you can see my date format is for example: 06-03-2017. The more "challenging" part is that in another component the date From and date To must have a time space of year. If the time space is more than a year a message should be appeared the the time space must be of a year at max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [synchronous validation](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/syncValidation/) function in Redux Form is given all of the form values. It seems like it would be pretty easy to say:

```
if(values.to.before(values.from) {
  errors.from = 'Must be before'
}
```

Alternatively, if you are doing ["field-level" validation](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/fieldLevelValidation/), the second parameter to [the `validate` function](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/Field.md/#-validate-value-allvalues-props-error-optional-) is all the values of the form.